# Replace values in dataframe with values from series of different length

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I would like to replace values in a column of a dataframe with values from a series. The catch is that I only want to replace values that are designated by a mask and the series does not have the same length as the dataframe.

More specifically, I want to replace all the values that are not null with values from a series that contains one value for each non-null value in the dataframe.

Assume the column in the dataframe contains `[1,2,3,NaN,5]` and the series contains `[2,4,6,10]`

I naively thought that this might work

```
    df[pd.notna(df)] = s
```

But it will make the column look like `[1,2,3,NaN,NaN]`. I understand why it behaves this way, but I need to find something that will give me this: `[2,4,6,NaN,10]`

Comment: Are the two series have the same index?

Comment: They do not have the same index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The approach you tried is possible, but with some changes:

- Update some **individual** column, not the whole DataFrame.
- To "escape" from different index values, take *values* from
  the "updating" *Series*.

To show how to do it, let's define the DataFrame (*df*) as:

```
     A     B
0  1.0  11.0
1  2.0  12.0
2  3.0  13.0
3  NaN   NaN
4  5.0  15.0
```

and the "updating" *Series* (*upd*) as:

```
11     2
12     4
13     6
14    10
dtype: int64
```

As you can see, indices in *df* and *upd* are different.

To update e.g. *A* column in *df* the way you want, run:

```
df.A[df.A.notna()] = upd.values
```

The result is:

```
      A     B
0   2.0  11.0
1   4.0  12.0
2   6.0  13.0
3   NaN   NaN
4  10.0  15.0
```

Comment: thanks. accessing the whole dataframe was just a mistake when writing the q. the values tip is what is great.